# DbgHelp.dll : calling SymGetModuleInfo64 from C#

Tags: c#, api, pinvoke, native

I have quite strange behaviour calling SymGetModuleInfo64 from C# code.I always get ERROR_INVALID_PARAMETER (87) with Marshal.GetLastWin32Error().I have already read a lot of posts regarding problems with frequent updates of IMAGEHLP_MODULE64 struct and I just downloaded latest Debugging Tools For Windows (x86) , loaded dbghelp.dll from that location and I was quite sure it would work.Nevertheless I am getting the same error.Can anyone point me what is wrong here?

IMAGEHLP_MODULE64 struct is defined in my code as follows :

```
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
  public struct IMAGEHELP_MODULE64
  {
   //************************************************
   public int SizeOfStruct;
   public long BaseOfImage;
   public int ImageSize;
   public int TimeDateStamp;
   public int CheckSum;
   public int NumSyms;
   public SymType SymType;
   [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValTStr, SizeConst = 32)]
   public string ModuleName;
   [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValTStr, SizeConst = 256)]
   public string ImageName;
   [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValTStr, SizeConst = 256)]
   public string LoadedImageName;
   //************************************************
   //new elements v2
   //*************************************************
   [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValTStr, SizeConst = 256)]
   public string LoadedPdbName;
   public int CVSig;
   [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValTStr, SizeConst = 780)]
   public string CVData;
   public int PdbSig;
   public GUID PdbSig70;
   public int PdbAge;
   public bool PdbUnmatched;
   public bool DbgUnmatched;
   public bool LineNumbers;
   public bool GlobalSymbols;
   public bool TypeInfo;
   //************************************************
   //new elements v3
   //************************************************
   public bool SourceIndexed;
   public bool Publics;
   //************************************************
   //new elements v4
   //************************************************
   public int MachineType;
   public int Reserved;
   //************************************************
  }
```

the piece of code that actually calls SymGetModuleInfo64 is like this :

```
public void GetSymbolInfo(IntPtr hProcess,long modBase64,out bool success)
  {
   success = false;
   DbgHelp.IMAGEHELP_MODULE64 moduleInfo = new DbgHelp.IMAGEHELP_MODULE64();
   moduleInfo.SizeOfStruct = Marshal.SizeOf(moduleInfo);

   try
   {
    success = DbgHelp.SymGetModuleInfo64(hProcess, modBase64, out moduleInfo);

    if (success)
    {
     //Do the stuff here
    }
   }
   catch (Exception exc)
   {
   }
  }
```

Im stuck here...always with error 87.Please someone points me to the right direction.

By the way modBase64 is value previously populated by :

```
modBase64 = DbgHelp.SymLoadModule64(_handle, IntPtr.Zero, fileName, null, baseAddress, size);
```

where _handle is process handle of process being debugged,fileName is path of current loaded module, baseAddress is address base of currently loaded module and size is of course the size of current loaded module.I call this code when I get LOAD_DLL_DEBUG_EVENT.
Edit :

Sorry, I forgot to mention that SymGetModuleInfo64 signature is like this :

```
[DllImport("dbghelp.dll", SetLastError = true)]
    public static extern bool SymGetModuleInfo64(IntPtr hProcess, long ModuleBase64, out IMAGEHELP_MODULE64 imgHelpModule);
```

---

First of all thank you for your answer.

1.Checked SymType and it's underlying type is really int.
2.Changed GUID struct to System.Guid
3.Added CharSet=CharSet.Auto in the definition of IMAGEHELP_MODULE64 struct.
4.Commented last two fields.
5.Checked the size of struct and it is 3264 bytes (Unicode) and 1672 bytes (Ansi) using Marshal.SizeOf(instance_of_the_struct).

dbghelp.dll is loaded from %windir%\system 32 folder, Im using windows server 2008 enterprise and still no success.Im still getting the same error - 87.

In second attempt I uncommented last two fields , and used dbghelp.dll from Debugging Tool For Windows (x86) directory since I downloaded newest version a couple of days ago and in SDK\inc there is dbghelp.h file which says that structure is using last two fields (v4) as like in this code snippet :

```
//
// module data structure
//

typedef struct _IMAGEHLP_MODULE64 {
    DWORD    SizeOfStruct;           // set to sizeof(IMAGEHLP_MODULE64)
    DWORD64  BaseOfImage;            // base load address of module
    DWORD    ImageSize;              // virtual size of the loaded module
    DWORD    TimeDateStamp;          // date/time stamp from pe header
    DWORD    CheckSum;               // checksum from the pe header
    DWORD    NumSyms;                // number of symbols in the symbol table
    SYM_TYPE SymType;                // type of symbols loaded
    CHAR     ModuleName[32];         // module name
    CHAR     ImageName[256];         // image name
    CHAR     LoadedImageName[256];   // symbol file name
    // new elements: 07-Jun-2002
    CHAR     LoadedPdbName[256];     // pdb file name
    DWORD    CVSig;                  // Signature of the CV record in the debug directories
    CHAR     CVData[MAX_PATH * 3];   // Contents of the CV record
    DWORD    PdbSig;                 // Signature of PDB
    GUID     PdbSig70;               // Signature of PDB (VC 7 and up)
    DWORD    PdbAge;                 // DBI age of pdb
    BOOL     PdbUnmatched;           // loaded an unmatched pdb
    BOOL     DbgUnmatched;           // loaded an unmatched dbg
    BOOL     LineNumbers;            // we have line number information
    BOOL     GlobalSymbols;          // we have internal symbol information
    BOOL     TypeInfo;               // we have type information
    // new elements: 17-Dec-2003
    BOOL     SourceIndexed;          // pdb supports source server
    BOOL     Publics;                // contains public symbols
    // new element: 15-Jul-2009
    DWORD    MachineType;            // IMAGE_FILE_MACHINE_XXX from ntimage.h and winnt.h
    DWORD    Reserved;               // Padding - don't remove.
} IMAGEHLP_MODULE64, *PIMAGEHLP_MODULE64;
```

I didnt have any success using both of these versions of struct and I have no more ideas.
As for address I am passing , Im pretty sure it is ok since I get it from SymLoadModule64 function as I stated before.

Hope someone will have idea what's going on here.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try changing the last parameter (imgHelpModule) from out to ref. For an out parameter, the CLR will not marshal any data into the function, so the API will not see the value you  put into SizeOfStruct.